# Batch read and rename from text file issue?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, rename

I'm a beginner with .bat files, and I'm attempting to rename multiple drawing (.dwg) files using a list generated in notepad. The notepad list contains a list of drawing numbers that look like this:

```
01013-13000p001
06301-12550p001
```

etc..

There is hundreds of them, and I want to take those numbers from the text and put it into a blank series of dwg files that are generic named for now (drawing.dwg, drawing(2).dwg, drawing(3).dwg etc..) I've only come up with a way to read a text file, but cant figure out how to take from the text file and rename multiple drawing files with it. Below is as far as I have gotten, after failed attempts of trying to take whats read from a text file and put it into the .dwg files. I plan on working this out in all the same directory, and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (dwgNumbers.txt.txt) do echo %%x 
pause
```

Comment: Are `drawing.dwg, drawing(2).dwg, drawing(3).dwg` all binary identical files?  Or is there a relationship between the current files and the new filenames?

Comment: @foxidrive The drawing file is just a blank generic drawing that I copied 20 times, and MS Windows assigned the (1, 2, 3 etc..) while being copied. I then want to take the names from the text file and rename those copied drawings with them.

Comment: In any particular order?

Comment: @unlemeat They are in no particular order.

Answer (score 1):

would

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (dwgNumbers.txt.txt) do echo copy /b "blank generic drawing.dwg" "%%x.dwg"
```

(as a batch line) do what you want? - note that the `ECHO` keyword is there to show what would be done. The `echo` keyword needs to be removed to actually execute the `copy`.

Comment: It does not seem to be working, it doesnt return any errors. But all it does is take the same drawing1.dwg (or "blank generic drawing.dwg") and return this to the command prompte: C:\Users\MRG123\Desktop\New folder>echo copy /b "drawing1.dwg" "01222-52003p001 .dwg"
copy /b "drawing1.dwg" "01222-52003p001 .dwg" #Its not renaming the blank files for some reason.

Comment: Hmm - are you sure the `echo` is appearing as you've shown, just after the prompt? The word `echo` shouldn't appear. Regardless, if you **REMOVE** the `echo` such that the line reads `...do copy /b...` then the `01222-52003p001 .dwg` and its friends from the textfile will be created from `drawing`.dwg`, saving you the hassle of creating 20 copies in the first place. Or are there 20 **DIFFERENT** 'blank' files that need to be copied?

Comment: Here is a screen shot of what I'm trying to do, that might explain it better: http://picpaste.com/screenshotDWG-F9vpcyX5.PNG

Comment: You didn't remove the `echo` statement

Comment: By the way, it will copy a single file to every new filename, and doesn't need all the duplicate copies.  It will just use one copy and make a stack of extra ones with the new filenames.

Comment: You also have a stray space between `%%x` and `.dwg`- which I'd included and foxidrive has corrected in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will take the numbers from `.txt`, renaming the existing `.dwg` files with the data readed. If there are more files that numbers in `.txt`, it will rename until number exhaustion, no more.

`for` loop is using a `dir` command to get the list of files to avoid the case of files that after being renamed falls under the filter of the `for` and gets reprocessed.

This code has a `echo` command included in rename line to prevent data loss in case of malfunction. When the output to console is what is needed, remove the `echo` command from the rename line.

```
@echo off

    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Read input file for numbers
    < dwgNumbers.txt ( 

        rem Process dwg files in directory
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.dwg') do (

            rem Get number from input file
            set "number="
            set /p "number="

            rem If there is a number, rename the file
            if defined number echo ren "%%~f" "!number!.dwg"
        )
    )

    rem Clean
    endlocal
```